# Backlit keyboard

Tags: keyboard, backlight

I have a dell vostro 3650 running newest Ubuntu install. [I read this laptop has a backlit keyboard.](http://reviews.dell.com/2341n/vostro-3750/dell-vostro-3750-reviews/reviews.htm?page=2&sort=submissionTime&dir=asc) I've researched how to turn it on with no luck. I've tried hitting the Fn F6 keys and the Fn right arrow key.

Comment: What about Fn+z?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Manufacture,

> ```
> Ports, Slots & Chassis    
> --snip--
> Optional backlit keyboard with numeric keypad
> ```

Also, i know that for any backlit keyboard that I have owned, I have had to cycle it dimmer **> FN + F5 <** then brighter **> FN + F6 <**

*NOTE: Key combos assumed from blurry photos on manufactures site!*